# The answer should return 4. idk how arguments[0] is returning 3 as its value and foo(3) is returning 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, console.log

```
var arguments = [1,2,3];
var arr=()=>arguments[0];

console.log(arr()); //returns 1

function foo(n){
    console.log(arguments[0]); //returns 3 should have returned 1 as arguments[0] is 1
    var f=()=>arguments[0]+n;
    return f();
}

console.log(foo(3)); //returns 6
```

The above is a JavaScript code
I have tried executing the code and the answer is correct I guess but I am unable to understand how `arguments[0]` is returning 3 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is foo(3) arguments[0] is 3 and then you add n (3) to it and get 6.  The global arguments[0] is equal to 1 so that is why you are seeing different results.  It is due to variable scope and is working how it should.